# Correct way to pass different v-model values for same parameter name in POST request

Tags: rest, api, vuejs2, submit, radio-group

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/codeXplorer/47qxczpf/34/)

I am assigning v-model values from a form to parameters in an api.  There is only one parameter in the api that I have to assign to both inputs i.e.: `name`.  The `name` is a required field.

Using `v-model` values of each input, if the first radiobtn is selected, it will return `null` for the value of `name`.  If the second radiobtn is selected, the user must enter text into the textbox.

I need to check whether the first radio button has been clicked OR the user entered text in the textbox and successfully pass the value of the first radiobtn or the textbox  to the same api parameter (`name`).
How can I do this?

HTML:

```
  <label class="radiogrp"><input type="radio" v-model="picked" name="default_user" value="reg" >Mary</label>
  <label class="radiogrp"><input type="radio" v-model="picked" name="new_usr" value="non-reg"><input type="text" v-model="new_user" ></label>
```

JS:

```
/* API parameters
name: (string) or (null)
*/

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    picked: Boolean,
    new_user: ""
  },  

/*  Two v-model form values for the one property in the API. */

submit_name(){
    this.$http.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",{ 
  name: this.picked || this.new_user})
  // ....then() etc.

}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `@input` event which can update the `new_usr` field on input changes.
Also you can watch `picked` variable to make sure if you toggle between radio buttons, `new_usr` should be reset.

```js
function callMe(){
    var vm = new Vue({
        el : '#root',
        data : {picked : '',new_usr:''},
        methods: {
          callApi(){
             let dataApi={}
             if(this.new_usr.length){
                dataApi.name=this.new_usr;
             }else{
                dataApi.name=this.picked;
             }
 
             console.log('You selected=', dataApi.name)
          }
        },
        watch:{
          picked: function (val) {
            this.new_usr='';
          }
        }
    })
}
callMe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
  <div>
  <label class="radiogrp">
  <input type="radio" v-model="picked" name="default_user" value="reg" >Mary</label>
  <label class="radiogrp">
  <input type="radio" v-model="picked" name="new_usr" value="non-reg">
  <input type="text" @input="evt=>new_usr=evt.target.value" :value="new_usr" >   </label>
  <button @click="callApi">hit me</button>
 
<span>Picked: {{ new_usr }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sweet!  I was thinking of using something like this in a method to get the value: `name: picked === "reg" ? null  : new_user`  but I wasn't sure.  Thanks, I'm going to use your solution.